# What is the function of the [0] in the reader.next()[0] line of the below code

Tags: kotlin, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val reader = Scanner(System.`in`)
    print("Enter two numbers: ")

    // nextDouble() reads the next double from the keyboard
    val first = reader.nextDouble()
    val second = reader.nextDouble()

    print("Enter an operator (+, -, *, /): ")
    val operator = reader.next()[0]

    val result: Double

    when (operator) {
        '+' -> result = first + second
        '-' -> result = first - second
        '*' -> result = first * second
        '/' -> result = first / second
        // operator doesn't match any case constant (+, -, *, /)
        else -> {
            System.out.printf("Error! operator is not correct")
            return
        }
    }

    System.out.printf("%.1f %c %.1f = %.1f", first, operator, second, result)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next()` returns a `String`, so the `[]` operator is translated to the [`get`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/get.html) method on `String`. With a 0 index, this call returns the first character of the `String`.

Answer (score 0):

If reader.next() returns an array then operator will have the value of the first element of the returned array.